# Can all of these COBOL statements be lumped together to use one write statement to file?

Tags: cobol

Can all of these declaration be lumped together so that I could just write parameter to a file?

Example: WRITE TEMP from myVariable

```
 01 LINE1       PIC X(80) VALUE 'String'.          
 01 LINE2.                                                        
    02 FILLER   PIC X(79) VALUE 'String'.   
    02 FILLER   PIC X(01) VALUE '>'.                              
 01 LINE3.                                                        
    05 R-TO     PIC X(10) VALUE 'String: <'.                     
    05 NEW-ADDR PIC X(69).                                        
    05 FILLER   PIC X(01) VALUE '>'.                              
 01 LINE4       PIC X(04) VALUE 'String'.                           
 01 LINE5       PIC X(80) VALUE 'String'.         
 01 LINE6.                                                        
    05 V-TO     PIC X(04) VALUE 'String'.                            
    05 ADDR6    PIC X(76).                                        
 01 LINE7       PIC X(80) VALUE 'String'.  
    SKIP1.
```

Comment: shouldn't `LINE4 PIC X(04) VALUE 'String'` be declared as `PIC X(80)` too?

Comment: This looks like a data formatting/display type problem, just show us what some typical values might be (e.g. NEW-ADDR, ADDR6 etc.) and how you want them displayed. We might be better able to answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
01  myVariable.
 05 LINE1       PIC X(80) VALUE 'String'.          
 05 LINE2.                                                        
    10 FILLER   PIC X(79) VALUE 'String'.   
    10 FILLER   PIC X(01) VALUE '>'.                              
 05 LINE3.                                                        
    10 R-TO     PIC X(10) VALUE 'String: <'.                     
    10 NEW-ADDR PIC X(69).                                        
    10 FILLER   PIC X(01) VALUE '>'.                              
 05 LINE4       PIC X(04) VALUE 'String'.                           
 05 LINE5       PIC X(80) VALUE 'String'.         
 05 LINE6.                                                        
    10 V-TO     PIC X(04) VALUE 'String'.                            
    10 ADDR6    PIC X(76).                                        
 05 LINE7       PIC X(80) VALUE 'String'.
```

"String" is six bytes, so it won't fit into the two four-byte fields.

This will do what you ask, but I'm not sure it is what you want.

Do you want a variable-length record with each element devoid of trailing spaces?

Comment: Each line should be 80 bytes long.  Sring is just a placeholder because I did not want to put up an sensitive information from the bank.

Comment: @DougHauf LINE4 only has four bytes at the moment. Yes, 80 bytes several times is no problem. 27,994 bytes are readily available for a single record, a little bit more if you want to stretch the size but lose out on disk space (you'd only get one record per track, and the rest of the track would be empty). Everything under a single 01-level can be written at one go.

Comment: @DougHauf And what happened?

Comment: The only thing that was printed was Line1 and the rest was not printed.

Comment: @DougHauf Check that your FD does not define 80-bytes records only. Your recordsize will be 560 bytes, so the FD needs to have an 01-level that is the same size. This also needs to be reflected in your JCL as well.